# Laravel : Destroy method triggering select from table when Model is injected into it

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

```
public function destroy(
    SubmissionType     $submissionType,
    int                $id
) {
    return response([], 200);
}
```

This code triggers

> select * from table where id = 1 and deleted_at is null limit 1

Why is this happening? I don't want it to run the select query automatically. I want to inject a dummy model and write a test this automatic behavior is throwing 500 internal server error.

Comment: What error is it throwing? It's automatically retrieving the model because of the route model binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding Can you show your route files?

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravl` you have dependency injection and model binding. In your case it means you can inject models into your control and it will automatically fetch it from the Database, this is quite nice in most cases.

So imagine your route.

```
submissiontypes/{submissionTypeId}
```

If you define your destroy method as follows nothing will be triggered in the database.

```
public function destroy(int $submissionTypeId) {

}
```

If you want to do model binding, you do as follows. This will tell `Laravel` to fetch your submission type on the submissionTypeId and automatically load your SubmissionType model.

```
public function destroy(SubmissionType $submissionType) {

}
```